# Consistent look between forms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Say I have 2 forms. Both of them have the same height / width.

Form 1 has a button which opens Form 2.

When I click the button, Form 2 jumps a little bit to a different location than Form 1.

So I guess my question is. how do I set up so this transition is smooth, like the new form is where form1 was.

Do I have to set this up in the properties? Or is there a better way? Right now, both of my forms are default forms. I looked at MDI thing, and that's not what I want. I just wanted to know if there is something I am missing.

Comment: should form1 be unusable if form2 is open?  Are you familiar with Modal?

Comment: Yes, I did read up on modal. I want form1 to be hidden...Seldman22 method works perfectly. Please let me know of any other way I should know...Thank you!

Comment: his answer doesn't make it hidden, it makes it modal.

Comment: hmm...could you please give me some more info or links to read up on....the thing is...so now....with the sample code I was given by seldman22, it opened the new window where form1 was...that is what I wanted, But if I move form2 to a new position now and close it...Form1 stays where it previously was....I want form1 and form2 to stay at the same place interchangeably....where ever I move...I don't know if I made much sense...

Comment: @buzcrawl, you don't need `....` after every phrase you type. It makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

When you open your second form use this:

```
Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
secondForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Then in your `Form2 Load` event set the location like this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = Owner.Location; // Owner is Form1.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `Location` property of your form as below. The x and y coordinates start at the top left corner. For example, (0,0) would place your form at the top-left window of your screen.

```
Form1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: `CenterParent` centers MDI Forms withing the container (parent) from. This is not the same as the owner specified by `this` here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Location` of the new form to be the `Location` of the old form:

```
newForm.Location = Location;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormStartPosition.Manual` as `StartPosition`, otherwise Windows will determine the start position.

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.StartPostition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form2.Location = this.Location;
form2.ShowDialog(this);
```